# How I can save a screenshot of an iPhone application?

Tags: iphone, ios, screen-capture

I want to take a screenshot of an iPhone or iPad application to share.

How is that accomplished?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Press the home button and the sleep button simultaneously. Newer phones have the sleep,on the side instead of the top but save images the same.

This will save a picture of the current iPhone screen to the *"Photos"* application. From there, you can either email it to anyone you want or sync it to your computer.

[image: buttons to press]

Assistive touch also works on newer iOS versions.

- [How can I create iPhone screenshots without the lock button?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/17728/how-can-i-create-iphone-screenshots-without-the-lock-button)

On iOS 11 screen recording might be if use for capturing transient events where your reflexes or the device itself isn’t responsive enough at the correct moment.

- [How do I take a screenshot in iOS without hitting the Home Button and the Power Button?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/222936/how-do-i-take-a-screenshot-in-ios-without-hitting-the-home-button-and-the-power)

Comment: [Illustration](http://www.examiner.com/images/blog/wysiwyg/image/iPhoneScreenshot.jpg) to complement your answer. :-)

Comment: Works on iPhone6 (although sleep is now button on top right  side)