# How can I create iPhone screenshots without the lock button?

Tags: iphone, screen-capture

Is there any way to create a screenshot of an iPhone without using the combination home+lock button? Is there an app for jailbroken phones? Something else?

I do not have a Mac; only Windows.

Comment: It doesn't not answer the question due to the last line in the OP's question, but I would like to point out that Xcode is capable of taking device screenshots. Both versions 3 and 4. Plug your iOS device into your computer, open Xcode, and go to the Organizer window if it doesn't start up into it. There you should be able to choose your device, and go to a 'screenshot' tab. There will be a button to take a screenshot, and immediately save it to your computer.

Comment: @Florian Why do you want to change the shortcut? If one of the buttons is broken, just get it fixed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Go to settings>General>Accessibility>Scroll down>AssistiveTouch

Turn it on.

Then you just click the home button and it gives you the option of screenshot if you do this:
Click device>More>Screenshot and you are done!

Answer (score 6):

Yes, there is. After you have jailbroken, install Activator. In there you can assign another activation method for taking a screen shot. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

I just found out the solution: go to the Activator app, click on a gesture you want to use, keep scrolling down until you find "Take A Screenshot". Mine is now set up to where I can push both volume buttons simultaneously and bam, screen shot captured!

Answer (score -4):

An alternative would be to simply take a picture of the screen with a camera.

Answer (score -4):

I'm sure there is not another way to do screenshots.