# How do I take a screenshot in iOS without hitting the Home Button and the Power Button?

Tags: iphone, screen-capture, touch-id

I would like to take a picture of [this Apple Pay popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pc9FY.jpg), while TouchID is active. However this seems impossible to do, since the TouchID sensor is also the home button, which prevents a screenshot from being taken.

Is there any alternative to taking a screen shot?

Comment: @danielAzuelos because that is the feature I want to take a picture of

Answer (score 13):

You could enable AssistiveTouch in Settings > General > Accessibility and then clicking on it's icon, and tapping Device > Take Screenshot.

Answer (score 12):

Use your fingernail - don't let your fingerprint touch the sensor and it will not dismiss...

Comment: +1 Fingernail's the one. Since I got a 6S, I've learned to use a fingernail if I ever want to read what may be on the lock screen before it unlocks. Darn thing is just too fast on fingerprint recognition ;) For a screenshot, I also make sure to hit the side button slightly before the home button, can prevent mis-reads too.

Comment: Instead of fingernail, it might work better to use a different finger (my iPhone doesn't recognize my pinky since I haven't added as a fingerprint)

Comment: @Tetsujin Can't you just unlock it with the power button?

Comment: @Kevin - of course… if you remember. 7 years of pressing the home button takes some unlearning.

Answer (score 5):

On iOS 10 and below, you need an external assist. Connect the iPhone to a Mac over USB and there are multiple free apps to grab a screen shot at your convenience without pressing any keys.

Xcode is the Mac OS X app I'd start with to grab screen shots.

On iOS 11, screen recording is build in, so you can record the action and extract a still frame if desired using various apps.

Answer (score 3):

Open QuickTime and create a new movie recording.   Record the screen on your iPhone using Apple Pay.  Move the playhead to the desired location for the screenshot and copy the frame using Command-C.

Now open the Preview app and select "New from Clipboard" under "File" from the main menu to get your screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using one of your fingers TouchID isn't associated with, like your pinky. If you have set up TouchID with all your fingers, you can use your elbow. Or your nose. Or your chin.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from hitting the home button and using Assistive Touch to do the screenshot. You can also use Apple's AirPlay feature to mirror your iOS screen to Windows or Mac via Wi-Fi, and then take screenshot. It also works.

Source Link: http://showmore.com/screenshot-iphone-6s.html